# Inheritance of font-lock-comment-delimiter-face

Tags: faces, comment, delimiters

How does inheritance of `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` work with `font-lock-comment-face`?

The following uses a different colour for the comment delimiter by setting the foreground colour to `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` after `font-lock-comment-face`.

I want to add a keybinding to change the colour of comments, but keep the colour of the comment delimiter the same.  Would I have to change
the foreground colour of `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` everytime I change `font-lock-comment-face`?

```lisp
 (if (eq 'dark (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode))
 
     (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face nil
             :foreground "#00FF00")   ; for dark theme
 
   (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face nil
               :foreground "#00FFFF") )   ; for light theme

(defun richkov-annotation-typeface (chroma)
"Set the foreground colour for comments.
CHROMA  Intensity Key used for setting colour of comments ."

  (message "richkov-annotation-typeface ")
  (let* ( (colors richkov-annotation-chroma)
          (levels
          (alist-get (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode) colors)) )
 
   (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face
      `(:foreground ,(alist-get chroma levels)))

   (copy-face 'font-lock-comment-face 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face) ))

(defun richkov-annotation-sweep ()
   "Cycles through the colour chroma for comments.
Colours are determined by `richkov-annotation'."
   (interactive)

   (pcase richkov-annotation-contrast
     (1
        (richkov-annotation-typeface 'low)
        (setq richkov-annotation-contrast 2))
     (2
        (richkov-annotation-typeface 'mid)
        (setq richkov-annotation-contrast 3))
     (_
        (richkov-annotation-typeface 'high)
        (setq richkov-annotation-contrast 1)) ))


(defun richkov-annotation-keytrigger ()
"Key trigger for rapid execution of richkov commands"
   (interactive)
   (global-set-key (kbd "H-;") #'richkov-annotation-sweep))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emacs inheritance of font-lock-comment-delimiter-face](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70559/emacs-inheritance-of-font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)

Comment: You seem to be posting the same question over and over...

Comment: If you inherit from a face using the `:inherit parent-face` construct, and your face doesn't define a property like `:foreground`, any change to the parent face will immediately also affect your face. Using race-remap is not really necessary unless in very special conditions. Also, instead of checking background mode using an `if`, it's better to define a face with *face specifications* for light and dark modes.

Comment: Have deleted the other postings. Just getting confused by the whole inheritance thing.

Comment: Can you update the question with that you are trying to accomplish? Do you want them to be the same, or do you want them to be different?

Comment: I am seeing whether I can set `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` attributes, then changing `:foreground` to `font-lock-comment-face` without this changing the changes previously done to `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`.

Comment: Can you try the same, but without using `face-remap-add-relative`? Also, can you show how the definitions for `font-lock-comment-face` and `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` is before your code (do they have their default values)?

Comment: How can I know their default values?  My theme or something else could change them.

Comment: Have done `set-face-attribute`.

Comment: There is a difference between `copy-face` and inheriting from a face. With `copy-face` you copy how it looks "right now". However, if you change the original face, the copy won't change. If you use the `:inherit` attribute, both will change if you change the original.

Comment: Could you show how inherit can be used on this?

Comment: `(set-face-attribute 'my-face :inherit 'my-other-face)`. However, the default definition of `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` already inherits from `font-lock-comment-face`. Hence, if you use the original definition, all you need to do is to modify `font-lock-comment-face`.

Comment: Thought it would be more complicated than that.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: I have a question.  If I set an attribute `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`, will it get overwritten when I update the attribute in `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`?  Noticed some situation where calling `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` before `font-lock-comment-face`, would reset the foreground attribute of the delimiter defined in `font-lock-comment-face`,

Comment: If an attribute in a face is set (no a non-nil value), it is used. Otherwise the attribute is inherited from the parent face (or faces). If none provide one, it is taken from the default face.

Comment: I think I understand now,  If I set the foreground to `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` to some colour (e.g. green), it would not matter whether the foreground to `font-lock-comment-face` is changed later on (e.g. to red).  The comment delimiter foreground would still continue to be green.  Is my understanding correct an this point regarding inheritance?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.